# Not able to create a Module using Android Studio 2.1.1

Tags: android, android-studio

Anyone have any ideas why this is happening? In Windows, when I right-click on the root of my project, I go to New -> Module. This is what I am shown

[image]

It used to be a lot more simpler and actually auto-generate a proper Android Module, complete with directories.

I have the latest version of Android Studio installed. Here is the version I have.

[image]

I was expecting to see something along the lines of the following:

[image]

Comment: Are you in Android or Project view? I guess it's the latter. Switch to Android view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem cannot be reproduced in the latest Android Studio 2.2.1 Canary that was announced today at Google I/O.

[image]

[image]